# Failed to read data from firebase firestore after Changing the device date (Android and emulator) for nearly 30 days

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i'm developing a quiz app. it is working fine.
but when i change the device date like more than 30 days, it is unable to read data from firestore.
see my code

```
     private fun getDataforDQuiz() {

    val docRef = db.collection("MonthlyQuiz")
        .document(getQuizNum.toString())
    docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                val x = documentSnapshot.toObject<QuizModelClass>()
                if (x != null) {

                    if (x.img != "" && x.img.isNotEmpty()) {
                        activity?.let {
                            Glide.with(it)
                                .load(x.img)
                                .fitCenter()
                                .into(imageViewToShow)
                        }
                    } else {
                        imageViewToShow.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                    correctAnswer = x.answer
                    radio_pirates.text = x.a
                    radio_ninjas.text = x.b
                    radio_donny.text = x.c
                    radio_monny.text = x.d
                    text_to_show.text = x.text
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            
            Toast.makeText(activity, "failed to load data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
     }
```

my QuizModelClass

```
       class QuizModelClass {
         var a: String = ""
         var b: String = ""
         var c: String = ""
         var d: String = ""
         var answer: String = ""
          var img: String = ""
         var text: String = ""

      constructor(
            A :String,
            B:String,
            C:String,
            D:String,
            Answer:String,
            Img:String,
           Text:String,
      )
      {
           a=A
           b=B
           c=C
           d=D
      answer=Answer
         img=Img
         text=Text

         }

   constructor() {}
    }
```

I have three functions for daily, weekly and monthly quizzes. First two are working fine.
my doubt is does firestore impose any limitations on reading data for changing the dates ?
i have also noticed i can't create a new account when i changed the date. and also can not login.

i'm getting the toast message "failed to load data"
my database

```
      MonthlyQuiz (collection)
                 1(document)-> data
                 2(document)->data
```

[my data base structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSTxR.png)

getQuizNum.toString() is just a number to reference the document in quiz collection. I save the previous quiz number in shared pref and use it to get next month quiz data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate what does `getQuizNum.toString()` return.

Comment: i've updated it. please check.

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the content of your `QuizModelClass` class.

Comment: i've edited question and added the content of the model class.